How can I download official WhatsApp on a phone that doesn't link with Google?
I use a Huawei Nova Y60 which is a bit difficult for me to get official WhatsApp because my phone doesn't link with anything from Google or in the form of Google.
How can I download official WhatsApp on a phone that doesn't link with Google?

Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Use alternative store like apkmirror, apkpure, etc. Here is a link to the latest version: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/whatsapp/whatsapp-2-24-22-76-release/

WhatsApp provides direct downloads on their official site. Click "Download WhatsApp directly" to download the APK file, then run it to install the app.
Other APK mirroring sites also provide the APK file:

APK Mirror
APK Pure

However, WhatsApp also needs Google Play Services to work. For Huawei devices, please follow How to get Google (Play) Services on Huawei phones bought in China?.
